# C#.Net & MySQL Database Login error how to fix

Tags: c#

Pro devs, I have a problem with my code in c#.net and I knew you can help me. the problem is in the Login code, every time I entered a value that is existed in the database it says "Username or password is incorrect" and when I entered a value that does not exist in the DB it says again "Username or password is incorrect" please help me thank you.

I have tried to edit the query and remove the open close in the asterisk but the output is the same.

```
public void checkLoginAccount()
    {
        frmMain frmLogin = new frmMain();
        con = new MySqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=alpine;port=3305;database=pos_db;pooling=false;SslMode=none";

        con.Open();
        string qry = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pos_db.tbllogin WHERE BINARY Username=@user AND BINARY Password=@pass";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", frmLogin.txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", frmLogin.txtPassword.Text);

        int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

        if (count != 0)
        {   
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Either username or password is incorrect!");
            return;
        }
        con.Close();
        con.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: What file is the `checkLoginAccount` method in?

Comment: the checkLoginAccount method is from another class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new form instance in your function:

```
 frmMain frmLogin = new frmMain();
```

So the username and password are always empty here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", frmLogin.txtUsername.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", frmLogin.txtPassword.Text);
```

You need to use the right instance of your form.

Comment: Basic debugging checking the variable value. Good catch.

Comment: Elias N What do you mean I need to use the right instance of my form?

Comment: I remove the new form instance "frmMain frmLogin = new frmMain" and use the original name of my form and I get a syntax error shows "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property".

Answer (score -1):

Try reading the rows and count in the code. That should look something like this:

```
string qry = "SELECT Username FROM pos_db.tbllogin WHERE BINARY Username=@user AND BINARY Password=@pass";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(qry, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", frmLogin.txtUsername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", frmLogin.txtPassword.Text);

        mySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if(reader.Read() == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Either username or password is incorrect!");
            return;
        }
```